# User manual for Sony PCG-252L to find the location of the video card

Tags: graphics-card, sony-vaio, documentation

I took apart my Sony PCG-252L, but can't find a video card. Any of you know where I could find a manual to help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computer likely has an integrated video card, which means the video card is not a separate card you can take out, but is built into the motherboard.

[Manual](http://www.docs.sony.com/reflib/docget.asp?manualid=95743&template_id=1&region_id=1&DL=)

Comment: i have a problem with my screen - it went WHITE. some forums suggest that it's the ribbon connector to the monitor that went bad. any idea where that might be?